# Is this a new bug? Size of Safe Area at Storyboard - Landscape Mode - XCode Version 14.2 (14C18)

Tags: xcode, version, landscape

I want to work on a new project but please please see the photo below.

Is there a change that I am not aware of?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there appears to have been an Interface Builder(IB) change, i.e. bug, introduced in one of the later versions of Xcode. On a private forum, students have noted this change.

Fortunately the safe area constraints should work as intended on a device or a simulator.

For example, a view(in orange) was added with constraints to the safe area. Landscape in IB looks like this:
[image]

However, when that same view is running on a simulator in landscape mode the view looks like this, which I think is the intended layout:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I did understand this because it is a new bug in InterFace Builder (Storyboard). But it's successfully working no any problem.