# Xcode safe area moved and now can't edit layout

Tags: xcode, autolayout, safearea

In Xcode I'm trying to add some auto layout constraints to my app, but in the Interface Builder the bottom button keeps pinning to the bottom of the screen. That's technically doing what I told it to do, which is alignment to the safe area. The problem is, the safe area shouldn't be there. I don't know how, why, or when the safe area moved, but I currently have no idea how to move it back. The options in the size inspector are greyed out so I can't change it manually (see picture).
What am I doing wrong?

[image: size inspector not changeable]

But when running the app simulator, the layouts are correct and the button areas above the little line.
[in simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZrXj.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have connected a **Present Modally** segue.

When designing in Storyboard, Xcode doesn't know the run-time size of the presented controller.

For example, if we have this controller layout (root view background is set to red):

[image]

and set that controller to Initial Controller then run the app, we get this (as expected):

[image]

However, if we **present** that controller modally, we get this:

[image]

Notice that the bottom looks the same, but the **Top** doesn't show a portion of the red root view. That's because the *presented* controller no longer covers the safe-area at the top of the device.

To really see what's going on, we run the app on an iPad and present that controller modally:

[image]

Now, neither the Top nor the Bottom will be effected by the safe-area, so we don't see the red root view in either place.

So... in Storyboard, if we add the present segue connection, it looks like what you're seeing:

[image]

If we change the Device during Storyboard design to an `iPad Pro 12.9"` layout, it looks like this:

[image]

You may find it easier to complete your layout design in Storyboard ***before*** connecting the **Present Modally** segue.

Comment: I thought I had finished it before connecting the sequel. Either something glitched up, or an edit messed up the layout or something.
So if I had completed the layout BEFORE connecting the segue you think this annoying design layout won't happen?
Your explanation was very helpful though, thank you!

Comment: @ConnorMichaelWinter - if you delete the Segue now, it will go back to the "normal" safe-area layout. You can then make any layout adjustments you need, and then re- connect / create the Present Modally Segue.

Comment: @ConnorMichaelWinter - if this solved your issue, you should "Accept" the answer for the benefit of others who may have a similar question.

Comment: Thanks but it didn’t work. 
After disconnecting the segue, the layout on interface builder did go back to being correct. But the second I remade the segue it went back back to pushing the button right to the bottom and the safe area down a bit. I don’t know why.

Comment: @ConnorMichaelWinter - I think you're focusing on the wrong thing... Storyboard / Interface Builder gives you a **simulated** layout, which will *usually* look the same as it does at run-time, but not always, and very often with minor differences. At run-time, a **presented** controller will look different depending on the device and on device orientation. That's why a big goal in UI design is ***adapting*** to different sizes and hardware....

Comment: @ConnorMichaelWinter - the fact that the layout is correct when the segue **is not** connected, and the layout is correct *at run-time* when the segue **is** connected, shows that it is working as intended.

Comment: But why wouldn’t it show the correct layout during a connection on the interface builder? Seems like a bit of a design flaw that it doesn’t actually show you what the layout will actually be on a device unless you run it in simulator only.

Comment: @ConnorMichaelWinter -- *design* flaw or ***designer*** flaw? Xcode Storyboard / Interface Builder can only give you an approximate representation, as it doesn't know which device will be used at run-time. As I said in my answer, *You may find it easier to complete your layout design in Storyboard before connecting the Present Modally segue* -- and that would, in fact, be my recommendation.

Comment: But I already did that.

Comment: Plus what nonsense is this “it doesn’t know what device it’ll use? You literally select which device it’ll use. That’s the whole point of the interface builder auto layout set up. So that it can run on a variety of devices. And the device isn’t the problem. It’s the interface builder screen not showing the correct layout when the simulator does.

Comment: @ConnorMichaelWinter - no software is completely bug-free... You may not be aware, but Xcode 14 Storyboards completely botched safe area when designing in Landscape Orientation ([one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75437063/is-this-a-new-bug-size-of-safe-area-at-storyboard-landscape-mode-xcode-vers)). Perhaps worth noting -- minor differences between Simulator and Hardware Device also crop up now and again. In any case, I believe we answered your question?